# Environment variables "not sticking" in Windows 8.1 batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file that will let me change my Java home and the path:

```
@echo off
echo Setting JAVA_HOME
set JDK6_PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45
set JAVA_HOME=%JDK6_PATH%
echo Setting PATH
set NEW_PATH=%JDK6_PATH%\bin\;%PATH%
set PATH=%NEW_PATH%
echo %PATH%
echo Display java version
java -version
pause
```

It continues to point to my Java 1.7 version.  I've tried using setx instead of set, and I've also tried running the batch file as administrator, but nothing seems to stick.

I've also tried this in cygwin (using a bash script) and powershell, and the changes don't stick in either of them, either.  Is there something in particular I need to do to get the changes to stick?

Comment: What do you mean by "stick"?  Your `java -version` line there still shows `1.7.0`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I wasn't specific.

Comment: Is there a java.exe in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45`?  Or do you need to add the JRE directory to the path specifically?

Comment: There's a java.exe in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin, but it isn't modifying the PATH at all.

Comment: The `set` command in a shell script (batch file) only sets the variable inside that shell session. It does not propagate the variable to other processes.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because there's a space in "Program Files"?

What if you put the path to java in quotes.  I use a mac, so you might have to play with the placement of the quotes ...

```
set JDK6_PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45"


set JDK6_PATH=C:\"Program Files"\Java\jdk1.6.0_45
```

Comment: The quotes should not be inserted into the variable because they're not a part of the directory name. (The " character is for command-line parsers; it is not a legal character in a directory name.)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - Adding the quotes will not solve the problem, but neither does it create a problem. Windows will remove the quotes when it tries to locate a file/folder using a path that contains quotes.

Comment: I've tried it with and without quotes, it doesn't seem to make a difference.  Could/should I try escaping out the space in Program Files?

Comment: @dbenham - I prefer not to rely on an implementation detail.

Comment: @user3731568 - As noted above, you need to explain what you mean by "stick". There is not enough information in your question.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific.  When I run the batch file, I expect my PATH and JAVA_HOME variables to change after it's done executing.  Right now if I run the batch file and then check my environment variables they remain unchanged.

Comment: Are you trying to change the `PATH` *outside* the batch file?  I was under the impression that the `java -version` line *inside* your batch file was showing the wrong version.

Comment: Setting an environment variable in the current process only changes it for the current process (and processes spawned by the current process). The change does not propagate to other processes.

Comment: @TrippKinetics, yes, the java -version line inside of my batch file doesn't show the proper version.  OK, thanks everyone, guess it's not possible.

Comment: @user3731568 - it's hard to tell what your actual question is, so it's hard to comment on what is possible or not. It seems like your question is really about environment variable propagation rules. I recommend searching for `environment variable propagation windows` or something similar.